# You are given two events A and B with the following conditions

Tags: probability

You are given two events A and B with the following conditions
$P (A | B) = 0.30, P(B | A) = 0.60, P(A∩B) = 0.18$.

a) Find $P(B)$.

b) Are $A$ and $B$ independent? Why?

c) Find $P(B∩A^{\prime})$.

For $a$, I think it’s $0.3$? 
For $b$, how do your know if events are independent?
For $c$, Is it $0.18 + 1 - P(A)$? This would make sense, I think but how do I know what to plug in for $P(A)$?

Comment: draw a venn diagram and label correct boxes, the rest should be easy to fill

Comment: What do you mean with $P(A \cap B')$? Is it $P(A\cap B^c)$?

Comment: @MariosGretsas It means the probability that something will not happen.

Comment: Do you know the conditional probability formula? The one that says $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{p(B)}$? Why don't you use it?

Comment: @zipirovich I haven’t been taught that, but I’ll try using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
$$0.3=\frac{0.18}{P(B)}$$
$$P(B)=0.6$$
Similarly,
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$$
$$0.6=\frac{0.18}{P(A)}$$
$$P(A)=0.3$$

$A$ and $B$ are independent because $P(A).P(B) = P(A\cap B)=0.18$